# How can I save configuration on Google Preference by using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I click on "OK" (see screenshot)?

I use Python 3.7, Selenium and Chrome as browser.

If you want to reproduce the notification box, go to https://www.google.com/preferences scroll down to "Region Settings" choose a region and click on "Save".

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--lang=en")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/preferences#languages')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="langten"]/div/div').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form-buttons"]/div[1]').click()
time.sleep(1)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/preferences')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="regionanchormore"]/span[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="regionoUS"]/div/div').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form-buttons"]/div[1]').click()
time.sleep(1)

# Now I need to click on "OK"
```

It seems, that the "OK" button doesn't have a `XPATH`.
I also tried to use `WebDriverWait` and `expected_conditions` as well as `driver.switch_to.alert`, but all those things didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what code you were trying before this, but here's my take on this

```
alertObject = driver.switch_to.alert
alertObject.accept()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After several tries, it finally work with this additional piece of code:

```
# Now I need to click on "OK"
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),'Timed out waiting alert to appear!')

    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    print("alert accepted")
except TimeoutException:
    print("no alert")

driver.quit()
```

Here you can find the doc regarding `Alerts`:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.alert

Answer (score -1):

use firefox...recreate the same situation and find the Xpath (or id)of that button and do something like this:
IWebElement okbtn = d.FindElement(By.Xpath("insert xpath here"));

```
okbtn.Click();
```

Comment: That will not work, it is an alert and not normal DOM button.